# Is there any point to using html elements in email campaigns?

Tags: html, email

Part of my job involves turning psd designs into html to be emailed out for email campaigns. In the past I've always gone through and converted everything to a suitable html element where possible but I'm now questioning whether there's any point to it?

Is okay just to use one giant image? I only ask because it seems using html elements is only really important if a) I want the information in the email to get to the client if images are blocked and b) for SEO.. yet search engines won't be indexing my code since it's all going through email.

If I'm pretty confident that the clients I'll be mailing *won't* have the images blocked, is it okay just to treat the entire email body as an `<img />`?

Thanks

Comment: even better, is there any point in email campaigns?

Comment: a lot of mail clients have images blocked by default. but that also affects html mails. other than that, you will be able to put links, allow people to select text, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it would be okay, but I wouldn't recommend it. Here are a few reasons why:

1. The readers won't be able to select and copy any of the content in the email, which in my opinion is really annoying.
2. You will not be able to have links in your email, the only thing you can link is the entire image.
3. If they do have images disabled, which i believe is fairly common, the wouldn't see a thing without downloading the image.
4. Increased email size due to the large image, which for mobile devices is a pain.
5. An image will not adapt to the window/display size. Text/HTML-based mails can at least break row if the content doesn't fit, to make it more readable.

And the list goes on. The other answers point out a number of additional reasons as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know that there is any definitive answer to this question, but here is my take on it:

- I think it’s a good idea to convert certain elements to text so that they can be copied or manipulated.  If you have a phone number, you may want that to be readable so that anyone with an automated dialer can click and complete the call.  Certain email programs might automatically convert an address to a link to the map. Those features won’t work if any of these elements are flattened into the jpg.
- For those mobile email clients that will not render the image on the screen (either because it’s just showing the preview or hasn’t yet downloaded the content) it’s useful to see some of the alternate text (and body content) before viewing the full image.
- I know you said that you are sure your clients won’t have images blocked, but you can’t really rely on that.  A well-meaning administrator who makes a change to the firewall could accidentally block all incoming images to the entire domain and your email will be worthless.
- Lastly, an HTML email with one line of code to load an image has a high possibility of being flagged as spam.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What about bandwidth concerns, for users viewing your email on a mobile device? If it's a large image, do you want to blow out their data caps?

Or users using assistive technology, for visually-impaired people. Such as a screenreader(text to speech).The real text is helpful for scenarios like that.